# Make user email field unique

Tags: go, go-gorm

Following is my entiry defined

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    FirstName string `json:"first_name"  binding:"required"`
    LastName  string `json:"last_name" binding:"required"`
    Email     string `json:"email" binding:"required,email" gorm:"unique,not null"`
    Phone     string `json:"phone" binding:"required"`
    Password  string `json:"password" binding:"required"`
}
```

Every thing work fine, but it still accept duplicated emails. I also tried `unique_index` but that isn't working as well.

Comment: Do you have a unique index in the database? It can't "not work". The database index is what actually enforces the uniqueness.

Comment: The `tag` is `uniqueIndex` not `unique_index`, to create a unique you have to use `index:,unique` https://gorm.io/docs/indexes.html#Index-Tag

Comment: @RafaAcioly ```uniqueIndex``` isn't working either

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - this is what bothering me, I am using migration and gorm is not adding unique index to email

Comment: I tried this recently and auto migrate didn’t modify the table to add the unique property. I had to drop the table and have gorm recreate.

Comment: @BrianWagner tried this already, but same result

Answer (score 1):

There is a little typo on your code,

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    FirstName string `json:"first_name"  binding:"required"`
    LastName  string `json:"last_name" binding:"required"`
    Email     string `json:"email" binding:"required,email" gorm:"unique,{Over here}not null"`
    Phone     string `json:"phone" binding:"required"`
    Password  string `json:"password" binding:"required"`
}
```

Change the comma after unique to semicolon and it should work.

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    FirstName string `json:"first_name"  binding:"required"`
    LastName  string `json:"last_name" binding:"required"`
    Email     string `json:"email" binding:"required,email" gorm:"unique;not null"`
    Phone     string `json:"phone" binding:"required"`
    Password  string `json:"password" binding:"required"`
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"`   

type User struct {
FirstName string `json:"first_name"  validate:"required"`
LastName  string `json:"last_name" validate:"required"`
Email     string `json:"email" validate:"required,email,unique=Email"`
Phone     string `json:"phone" validate:"required"`
Password  string `json:"password" validate:"required"`}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is unfortunately not correct. `unique=FieldName` in validator v10 should be placed on Slice level, not field itself. 
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10#hdr-Unique